# AWS Host Multiple Domains On One EC2 Instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualhost, amazon-route53

I have one **EC2 instance** running with an **Elastic IP** of `54.82.145.116`. My `vhost.conf` file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/brentrichison.com
    ServerAdmin brent@brentrichison.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName brentrichison.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/brentrichison.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName greyspace.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/greyspace.io
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tlsbaseball.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tlsbaseball.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tm.brentrichison.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tm
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tls.brentrichison.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tlsbaseball.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The first domain, `brentrichison.com`, works fine. The subdomains for that domain also work fine. The other domains, `tlsbaseball.com` and `greyspace.io` do not work at all.

Each domain has a Hosted Zone on Route 53. Each domain's "A" Record points to `54.82.145.116`. Each domain has its own SOA Record, and each zone has its own DNS Records.

Does anyone have any ideas why my other two domains won't resolve? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see from the whois greyspace.io and tlsbasebll.com are pointed to Route53 servers, but they're not answering my queries.  Look at the hosted zones in Route 53 and verify that the NS servers specified there are the ones from Amazon and line up with what you have in DNS.  It's pretty easy to swap them or get them wrong when you're doing multiple domains.

```
$ whois greyspace.io

Domain : greyspace.io
Status : Live
Expiry : 2017-11-25

NS 1   : ns-1566.awsdns-03.co.uk
NS 2   : ns-1297.awsdns-34.org
NS 3   : ns-1021.awsdns-63.net
NS 4   : ns-343.awsdns-42.com
$ dig @ns-343.awsdns-42.com greyspace.io -t soa

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns-343.awsdns-42.com greyspace.io -t soa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 27079
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;greyspace.io.          IN  SOA

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.193.87#53(205.251.193.87)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 24 10:19:01 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

Based on your comment below, it sounds like you registered these domains with amazon, and then recreated the hosted zone a few times.  Let's look a little closer at what that really looks like for, say, `greyspace.io`:

1. register with amazon

   1. as dns provider, amazon automatically creates a hosted zone to serve the 
      records associated with your domain, which generates the names of 
      nameservers willing to answer queries for that domain
   2. as a registrar amazon saves the `greyspace` registration data within the 
      `.io` registry, along with dns glue records that point requests for the 
      domain to the AWS Route53 servers from step 1

Now the domain's dns hsoted zone is "live", in that the whois data points to it.

2. you delete and recreate the dns hosted zone.  Upon deletion, the listed 
   nameservers aren't willing to answer these queries anymore, but they're 
   still listed in DNS

So all you have to do is go into your domain registration and update the whois 
listed nameservers to point to the new ones you got when you recreated the hosted zone.

On an unrelated note, why do you have this in here twice?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/brentrichison.com
    ServerAdmin brent@brentrichison.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName brentrichison.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/brentrichison.com
</VirtualHost>
```

2 sites with the same docroot?  I'm confused.  Aren't those actually the same site?

Comment: You must be on to something. My greyspace.io DNS in Route 53 is different than what you have. If AWS automatically generates DNS settings, why is whois not reflecting what AWS has? I deleted my Hosted Zone once or twice and started over, but that's been about a week, and the new DNS settings should have taken affect by now, no? Also, in answer to your question, the first one is `default:80`, meaning that anytime someone comes in on a subdomain that doesn't exist, i.e., blah.brentrichison.com, it will just point to my site. That was mostly me just experimenting and learning, though.

Comment: You probably failed to update the regisration side's DNS when you replaced the hosted zone.  Now that I know you registered with AWS I can provide some more insight.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I see now in Route53, you must update the new NS info under Registered Domains > Name Servers. I thought just doing this in the Hosted Zone was it, but there was one additional step. Thanks again!